# How to make istio an HTTPS proxy that forward backend based on URIs?

Tags: kubernetes, https, istio

I want to access the internal https service through istio in a k8s cluster. But as I known, a gateway with HTTPRoute can route individual HTTP requests, while it can only route to connections when I make an TLSRoute. how can I make configuration that can route HTTPS requests **by uri path**? like ingress do.

I made a GateWay configuration:

```
- hosts:
  - 10.50.176.77
  port:
    name: tls
    number: 15443
    protocol: TLS
  tls:
    mode: PASSTHROUGH
```

and VirtualService configuration：

```
tls:
- match:
  - port: 15443
    sniHosts:
    - 10.50.176.77
  route:
  - destination:
      host: console-web
      port:
        number: 8099
http:
- match:
  - uri:
      prefix: /login
  route:
  - destination:
      host: console-web
      port:
        number: 8099
- match:
  - uri:
      prefix: /auth
  route:
  - destination:
      host: console-auth
      port:
        number: 8098
```

the tls gateway work after I made a TLSRoute VirtualService configuration. the httpRoute configuration only take effect when an HTTP Gateway set. But I want to access the console-web,console-auth service by istio at browser use https, also these service is on HTTPS protocol.

Thank you!